# How can I enable keybord Samsung Galaxy S3 GT-i9300 Android version 4.1.1

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, keyboard

I can't find the keyboard in my Samsung Galaxy S3. I only found "Google Voice Typing":

In *Settings → Language and Input → Keyboards and Input methods* I have only *Google Voice Typing*.

What's wrong with my device? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it sounds strange that there should be no keyboard present, and as trivial as it might sound: Simply installing an alternative keyboard from the playstore should fix that. Take e.g. [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard), which is a very flexible one, and well rated (I'm using it myself on my tablets). Simply install it, and its settings should turn up at the place you've described. Optionally, add the dictionaries for the languages you like to have them (see the keyboard's playstore page, some are directly linked to the app).

### Do it from a PC/Laptop

As you currently have no keyboard available on your device, it might be difficult/impossible to use the playstore app on the device itself to install the above. You can still install it:

1. on your laptop/pc, open a web browser and go to `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard`
2. log in with the credentials of the Google account you use on your device
3. click the "Install" button, accept the permissions for the app (they are OK)
4. the keyboard will be pushed to your device

Once the installation has finished (you can see this in your device's notification area), you can go to the described place (*Settings → Language and Input → Keyboards and Input methods*) and make the new keyboard the default input method. With that final step, you problem should be solved.

### No Google-Account configured on the device?

In this case, installation via the web interface cannot work either, as the app-to-be-installed cannot be pushed to the device. Still, there is something you can do:

1. On your PC/Laptop:

   - Visit the Hacker's keyboard project's [download page](http://code.google.com/p/hackerskeyboard/downloads/list) and download the `.apk` file to your computer
   - if you don't have any file manager on your Android device:

     1. You will need the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) installed, or at least a "Mini variant" (the `adb`/`adb.exe` binary and, on Windows, its helper `.dll` files -- check the [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) tag and [its wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) for details, and see [QtADB](http://qtadb.wordpress.com/) for a simple, user-friendly variant working on Windows, Mac and Linux)
     2. When on Windows: Make sure you have the drivers for your Android device installed
2. On your Android-device:

   - Enable [unknown-sources](/questions/tagged/unknown-sources) to activate [side-loading](/questions/tagged/side-loading) (*Settings→Security:* Check "Unknown Sources")
   - if you don't have a file-manager app on your Android device: Enable [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) debugging (*Settings→Development:* Check *USB-Debugging*)
3. Connect your Android device with your PC/Laptop via USB cable
4. to install your `.apk`...

   - if you have a file-manager app on your Android device:

     1. simply copy the `.apk` to your device as you usually copy files there
     2. use your file-manager app to navigate to the `.apk`
     3. "tapp" the `.apk` file's entry. After asking your confirmation, the app will be installed. Skip all below -- you're done.
   - if you don't have a file-manager app on your device: use `pm install` via the ADB [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line) to install the `.apk` on your Android device (see [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=22547792&styleid=19) for more details on this -- usually it should be `adb pm install /path/to/download/*.apk`, replace the `/path/to/download` part with the full directory name of where you saved the `.apk` to).

Comment: thx,  but i can't access to playstore  with this s-voice , may should i install the new Android 4.2.2 Jelly Bean

Comment: Jaidi, you can visit the playstore with your browser from your pc/laptop, log in with your Google account's credentials, visit the keyboards page, and push the "Install" button. It then gets installed to your device automatically -- and as soon as it is, you can select it at the described place to be used as default input method.

Comment: i do it this but must connect to my device with my G mail and i can't with the s-voice !!!

Comment: Oh -- do you mean there is no Google account configured on the device? I will update my answer again with possibilities left in that case.

Comment: thx a lot :)  i add the hacker keyboard and it work good  but i have question  why  when i reset my device i only get the s-voice.

Comment: When you reset your device, the keyboard will be gone again, yes. But bookmarking this question, you can always restore it. Now you've got a working keyboard again, I also recommend to create an account, visit the playstore, and install the app again (so you don't miss any updates). As this answer solved your issue, it would also be nice if you "accept" it (hit the checkmark next to it) -- so it shows up as solution.